# Answer offset when navigating from link

Tags: bug, android-app

When I visit a [link on the PPCG sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9435/20198) the app doesn't scroll down far enough. This problem is especially apparent on the sandbox because it is easy to get lost in the huge list of answers.

Comment: I have the same problem, but even worse. It takes a good 5 minutes to load. I usually just give up and do it in Chrome, since it has pages.